# Add image to list items using Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add country image along with language using Angular JS.

```
<div ng-app class="nav">
<div></div>
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    {{selectedValue}}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="lang in languages"><a ng-class="{selected: lang==selectedValue}" ng-click="changeSelectedValue(lang)" href="#">{{lang}}</a></li>
    </ul>  

</div>
</div>

<script>
function MainController($scope) {
$scope.languages = ['<img></img>English','Espanol', 'Française', 'Italian'];
    $scope.selectedValue = 'English';

    $scope.changeSelectedValue = function(lang) {
        $scope.selectedValue = lang;
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RdNw4/6/

Am I missing any code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the image tag out of the languages array and rework your model so that the languages look something like:

```
$scope.languages = [ { name: 'English', image: '/images/english.png' },
    { name: 'Espanol', image: '/images/espanol.png' }
    etc.
];
```

Then change your markup to add an image tag:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="lang in languages">
        <img ng-src='{{lang.image}}' /> //for correct url
        <a ng-class="{selected: lang==selectedValue}" href="#">{{lang.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```